# JavaScript Scope: How to create anonymous functions with different values?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a number of buttons and I want to add a onclick function programmatically to each one.
I want these functions to know which button number they are attached to, but I don't want to parse the button-id to get the number. There must be a better way:

```
    require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/on"], function(dom, domReady, on) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            on(dom.byId("button"+ i), "click", function(e) {
                console.log("Number: "+ i);
            });
        }
    });
```

How do I add a function so that it correctly outputs the button number without doing this:

```
console.log("Number: "+ e.srcElement.id.substring(6));
```

Comment: check [this](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-3/) out, on using closures within loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    on(dom.byId("button"+ i), "click", (function(number){
        return function(e) {
            console.log("Number: "+ number);
        };
    })(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! But why? What do the brackets do in this case?

Comment: I use an [IIFE](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=Immediately-Invoked+Function+Expression) taking `i` as a parameter to return a function which uses the value of `i` at that point in the loop, so the closure is created for `number` instead of `i`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of IIFE. This was really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same via [`dojo/_base/lang::partial`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/_base/lang#partial):

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
    lang,
    dom,
    on
) {

    var button_onClick = function(i, event) {
        console.log("Number:", i);
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        on(dom.byId("button" + i), "click", lang.partial(button_onClick, i));
    }

});​
```

See a working example at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/KhsXB/

Comment: Thanks, that works too. Sadly I can't accept two answers to this question.